# JSON Schema to validate a JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

We are using JSON Schema to validate the editing of some business objects, and the Schema itself is editable (it rarely changes but we wanted to allow admins to amend via the product itself).

Validating the amendments of business objects via the schema itself is working well, but we want to ensure that any edits to the schema itself adhere to JSON Schema rules, is there a JSON schema to validate that a certain JSON is in fact a valid JSON Schema? I know it might sound like a philosophical question, but it is something we would love to have if possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema for the schema is called the "meta-schema" and is identified by the `$schema` keyword in your schema.  The Draft 2020-12 meta-schema can be found [here](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema).

Implementations should be able to validate a schema using its meta-schema for you.

You can learn more at https://json-schema.org/specification.html.